# Is it possible to use a single heroku dyno for multiple wordpress sites?

Tags: wordpress, heroku

I am considering deploying multiple instances of WordPress sites to Heroku using this buildpack:
https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mchung/heroku-buildpack-wordpress

I have never worked with Heroku before, so I am confused about the pricing.

**my question:**

Is it possible to use a single dyno and deploy multiple low-traffic wordpress sites there, or is it going to be one dyno per one site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Dyno per site.

When using the Wordpress buildpack Heroku provides a single Heroku dyno: this is because a Web Dyno can only listen to a port.
At deployment time your Dyno gets a url based on your project name (project.herokuapp.com).

Heroku has a free-tier (see [limitations](https://www.heroku.com/free)) so you can run all sites you need for free.

Alternatively I would suggest DigitalOcean: with 5$ per month you get a droplet where you can configure multiple sites/applications behind a single HTTP server (ie nginx).